# How to implement random items to display for a mapping function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a mapping function that iterates over an array of items. I already sliced the data to select only a small handful of data to display. However now I also want the mapping to select random items from the array.

```
const randomStocks = Math.floor(Math.random() * buckets.stock_count);
```

Here is my mapping function:

```
{bucket.stock_list.slice(0, 4).map((stock, index) =>
    {return(
            <Chip key={index} label={stock} />
            )}
)}
```

Where and how can I add my `randomStocks` in my mapping function while respecting the slicing of data?

Answer (score 2):

If your array is not immensely large, then a practical solution is to first *shuffle* your array randomly, and then to `slice` as you already do.

For shuffling you can use one of the answers provided in [How can I shuffle an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array):

> ```
> function shuffle(a) {
>     var j, x, i;
>     for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
>         j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
>         x = a[i];
>         a[i] = a[j];
>         a[j] = x;
>     }
>     return a;
> }
> ```

So then your code can be:

```
{
    shuffle(Array.from(bucket.stock_list)).slice(0, 4).map((stock, index) => {
        return(
            <Chip key={index} label={stock} />
        )
    })
}
```

The call to `Array.from` is only needed if you don't want to mutate the stock list itself, and keep its original order untouched.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how too, is there any way to get the shuffle not work during state changes?

Comment: I don't understand that question. If you don't want to shuffle, then don't call that function?

Comment: Maybe you want to call shuffle only once (and persist it), and not have it run in the same function as where you render?

Comment: Thank you, basically the shuffle happens every time a state changes on the page (as expected). I forgot that would happen. I will research about how to persist it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use following random integer generator from [`Math.Random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
const ITEMS_LIMIT = 4;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

const randomStocks = getRandomInt(0, buckets.stock_count - ITEMS_LIMIT);
```

You can then do

```
{
   bucket.stock_list.slice(randomStocks, randomStocks+ ITEMS_LIMIT).map((stock, index) => {
      return <Chip key={index} label={stock} />
   })
}
```

Comment: The second argument of `slice` is not a length. If this is fixed, it will return a random subsection of the array, which only makes the first selected item random. All the other selected elements are determined by that choice.